# Python subprocess.Popen with var/args

Tags: python, django, cmd, subprocess

i want to call a subprocess.Popen cmd with a variable but for reason it's not properly working

thats the error i got:

...

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: How is this related to [tag:django] and [tag:cmd]?

Comment: its a Django celery Task ;)

Comment: Just updated the post

Comment: Well, that's a simple python syntax problem. user.acc_addr is a string and you're providing a list of commands. What bash command are you actually trying to call?

Comment: So how can i place the string of user.acc_addr in that cmd?
I want that for each user account the field user.acc_addr is placed behind my cmd within my for loop. Its a internal tool of a client, can't say you the exact need or script name :( i dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All args have to be in a list like

```
check_addr = subprocess.Popen(['My command', user.acc_addr], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip()

# or for example
subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])
```

Comment: Almost, got it working like that: 

check_addr = subprocess.Popen(['mycommand' + ' ' + 'mycommandparams' + ' ' + address], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip()