# Why does the command and its arguments have to be in a list for subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I tried doing

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("ls -la /etc", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdout.read().decode()
```

Which gives me

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ls -la /etc': 'ls -la /etc'
```

---

Following

[Python subprocess.Popen with var/args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784997/python-subprocess-popen-with-var-args)

I did

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-la", "/etc"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdout.read().decode()
```

Which did work.

Why is that? Why do I have to split my command and its arguments? What's the rationale behind this design?

---

Python version:

```
3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17)
[GCC 7.3.0]
```

Comment: A convention I've seen is to pass your string, but `split` it so it becomes a list: `"ls -la /etc".split(' ')`

Comment: Giving the arguments as a list, which can also contain variables and expressions as the items, allow the underlying code to ensure proper quoting and prevent shell code injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Interesting how you use `/etc` and the error complains about `~/projects`...

Comment: wups forgot to rerun the code after changing the directory

Comment: @JacobIRR, ...it's a convention, but it's a *bad* one; please don't encourage it. Filenames with spaces will break badly that way. `shlex.split()` is a *bit* less buggy, but it's still better to have a human-generated list.

Comment: @KlausD., "ensure proper quoting"? It prevents any *need* for quoting at all; shell quoting is a shell construct; with `shell=False`, you're just passing a list of literal C strings, and so no quoting, proper *or* improper, is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### That's how **all** process invocations work on UNIX.

Under the hood, running a program on UNIX is traditionally done with the following steps:

1. [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) off a child process.
2. In that child process, open new copies of stdin, stdout, stderr, etc if redirections are requested, using the [`dup2()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) call to assign the newly-opened files over the file descriptors that are redirection targets.
3. In that child process, use the [`execve()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall to replace the current process with the desired child process. **This syscall takes an array of arguments, not a single string.**
4. [`wait()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) for the child to exit, if the call is meant to be blocking.

So, `subprocess.Popen` exposes the array interface, *because the array interface is what the operating system actually does under the hood*.

When you run `ls /tmp` at a shell, *that shell* transforms the string into an array and then does the above steps itself -- but it gives you more control (and avoids serious bugs -- if someone creates a file named `/tmp/$(rm -rf ~)`, you don't want trying to `cat /tmp/$(rm -rf ~)` to delete your home directory) when you do the transformations yourself.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess%20popen#popen-constructor), it's dependent on the `shell=` keyword argument on how a string will work vs a list (Bold indicates what is likely causing your experienced behavior):

> args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string or path-like object. By default, the program to execute is the first item in args if args is a sequence. If args is a string, the interpretation is platform-dependent and described below. See the shell and executable arguments for additional differences from the default behavior. Unless otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass args as a sequence.
>
> **On POSIX, if args is a string, the string is interpreted as the name or path of the program to execute. However, this can only be done if not passing arguments to the program.**

Further down...

> On POSIX with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:
>
> `Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])`
>
> On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies the default shell. The only time you need to specify shell=True on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a batch file or console-based executable.